# Xcode 4 code snippet without dragging it to the editor

Tags: xcode4, code-snippets

Is it possible to add a code snippet to the editor without dragging it from the code snippet library? (like writing "@int.." and then when the code sense shows up select `@interface`  and press some keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control click the code snippet icon, should bring up a popover.

In the popover click the edit button.

Edit the "Completion shortcut" field.

in your case you would simply enter "@interface"